# Adding a Second Tier to this Responsive Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, css

How would I add a second tier to the drop down items?

Below is the code I found on StackOverfow which will work great if I can add
the second tiers.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

#menuBackground {
  background: #2f3036;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#menuContainer {
  text-align: center;
}


/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 1px;
}


/*Style for menu links*/

li a {
  display: block;
  min-width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2f3036;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
}


/*Hover state for top level links*/

li:hover a {
  background: #19c589
}


/*Style for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  color: #2f3036;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px
}


/*Hover state for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a:hover {
  background: #19c589;
  color: #fff
}


/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none
}


/*Make dropdown links vertical*/

li ul li {
  display: block;
}


/*Prevent text wrapping*/

li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px
}


/*Display the dropdown on hover*/

ul li a:hover+.hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block
}


/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.show-menu {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #19c589;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%!important
}


/*Hide checkbox*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none
}


/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#menu {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
    white-space: initial;
  }
  /*Create vertical spacing*/
  li {
    margin-bottom: 1px
  }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%
  }
  /*Display 'show menu' link*/
  .show-menu {
    display: block
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="menuBackground">
  <div id="menuContainer">
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About ￬</a>
        <ul class="hidden">
          <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Portfolio ￬</a>
        <ul class="hidden">
          <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Web & User Interface Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This might help. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpQerE . (under about dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

To add a tier just open a new `ul` inside whichever `li` you want to have the sub section. You can see the example with `ul class="hidden`.

```css
.hide { display: none }

li:hover { color: red; cursor: pointer; }

li:hover > .hide { display: block }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>link
  
    <ul class="hide">
      <li>sub</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
   
  <li>deeper link
  
    <ul class="hide">
      <li>sub
      
        <ul class="hide">
        <li>sub</li>
       </ul>
      
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

 </ul>
```